# Finding equation of plane that passes through two planes and given point

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have plane such that $(0,-3,1)$ lies on the plane and is perpendicular to the planes $x+2y+3z=100$ and $3x-5y+4z=200$. What is the equation of this plane?

#### attempt:

We know $\vec{n_1}=(1,2,3)$ and $\vec{n_2}= (3,-5,4)$ are the normals of the given planes. Since the two planes are perpendicular to the plane we want to find, then we can find some $\vec{v} =(a,b,c)$  on the plane such that $ \vec{v} \cdot \vec{n_1} = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{n_2} = 0$. These equations gives $a+2b +3c = 0$ and $3a-5b+4c=0$. Let $c = t$, and solving the system, we find that $\vec{v} = ( - \frac{23}{11} t, - \frac{5}{11} t, t )$ is the vector that lies on the plane. With $t = 11$, we have $\vec{v} = (-23,-5,11)$ lies on the plane. and this is the normal of the plane we want. Since point $(0,-3,1)$ is in the plane, then we have $\vec{r} = (x,y+3,z-1) \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ and so

$$ -23x - 5y - 15 + 11z - 11 = 0 \implies -23x-5y+11z-26 = 0$$

is the equation of the plane we want.

IS this correct?

Comment: The mathematics seem good. The language, however, is a bit messy. For instance, what do you mean by "we can find some $\vec v$ _on the plane_"? On what plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write "we can find some $\vec{v}=(a, b, c)$ on the plane", if you mean that $\vec{v}$ is on the plane to find, then this is not correct. Indeed, "this is the normal of the plane we want", then it can not be on that plane. In addition, you can not actually write that $\vec{v}$ is "on a plane". If I define $A = (0, 0, 1)$ and $B = (1, 0, 0)$, I can write that the vector $\vec{AB}=(1, 0, -1)$ is on a given plane because I know where $A$ is, but you do not know the initial point of the vector $\vec{v}$.

I would also modify what you wrote about $\vec{r}$. If $R = (x,y,z)$ is on the plane to find and since $P = (0, -3, 1)$ is on this plane too, we have that $\vec{r} = \vec{PR} = (x, y+3, z-1)$ is on this plane. We also have that $\vec{v}$ is the normal of this plane, so that:
$$\vec{r}.\vec{v} = 0.$$

I only verified the reasoning and I do not know if the final equation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. I would shorten noting that an orthogonal vector to the plane  is the cross-product $\vec n=\vec n_1\times \vec n_2$, which is easy to calculate with determinants, and using the vector equation of the plane: if $\vec v$ is a vector of the plane, and $\vec v_0$ the given point, the equation is
$$\vec n\cdot v=\vec n\cdot \vec v_0.$$